# Should moderators lock posts without giving a reasoning for it?

Tags: support, comments, moderation, locked-question

I recently posted a [question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/592383). It was locked within the hour for a day. Now what I need to understand is why that was done, so I can rectify it. As a corollary, should moderators lock questions without giving a reason?

Answer (score 3):

The reason is always given in the lock message.

In your case, it's so that people actually bother to answer you instead of just commenting you, which breaks our system here.

The way you asked your question is likely to provoke comments and discussion rather than answers, at least with the current set of folks who are lightning-quick to jump on questions to comment them, but somehow can't ever be bothered to answer them.

If you're looking to have a conversation with people about this, then that should be in chat.

Comment: I'm not against this, but how does one ask for clarification from the OP? Chat is an option, but not everyone is comfortable talking there. For the question linked above, I'd have to wait 18 more hours to ask for clarification from the OP...

Comment: There is also the option of converting answers in comments to community wikis, as I've seen you do a few times before. Or add an immediate comment under the post explicitly asking people to post answers in the answer box, not in the comment section (as @AndrewLeach has done here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/591623/word-meaning-to-take-away-the-sophistication-of-something#comment1486385_591623).

Comment: What does the "lock message" refer to exactly? Maybe I'm not looking in the right place, but I don't see any message on the OP's question that explains why it was locked. (Or is this message is only available to the asker of the question?)

Comment: While I understand your arguments against excessive commenting, which you stated at a number of meta-pages, it seems to me that, even if one agrees with these arguments, there is something problematic about disabling comments on a particular question solely on the basis of a **suspicion** that it **might** generate excessive comments, **before** any such comments actually appear.

Comment: @jsw29 All answers in comments are excessive comments.

Comment: @Carmeister There's a blue banner on the question, "Locked for *time remaining*. Comments on this question have been disabled, but it is still accepting new answers and other interactions. [Learn more](https://english.stackexchange.com/help/locked-posts)." The lock reason isn't explicit, but can be inferred from what is locked: locking against new comments indicates that comments so far are there for the wrong reason.

Comment: @tchrist, assuming for the sake of argument, that 'all answers in comments are excessive comments', there is still a difference between a moderator's reacting **specifically** to such comments **after** they have been posted, and a moderator's disabling **all** comments just because the moderator believes that some answers-in-comments **might** appear. One may find the latter problematic even if one agrees with the latter.

Comment: Why are -all- comments disabled? Why not just delete the offending comments? Or, what I think is better, leave all the comments? The answers in comments are the most helpful in understanding the question, most of the other comments are, relatively, less helpful. So, of course, the right thing to do is copy the 'answer in comment' to an official answer (as community wiki).

Comment: @Mitch [Continuous abuse like this](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/592164) is why we can't have nice things: because **it ruins the SE system.** Moderators delete metric truckloads of answers in comments every single day. It has to stop.

Comment: If a question attracts a lot of comments it's normally because it's a question that needs improvement. People often answer in comments because they're not sure if they're answering the question or suspect the question will be closed. It's common in such situations to post a comment of the form "If you mean X the answer is something in the area of Y." The apparent rule that you're not supposed to answer low-quality questions also doesn't help. Other people could be encouraged to convert semi-answers in comments into proper answers, because answers in comments almost never meet SE standards.

Comment: @StuartF People aren't much interested in making an answer out of someone else's comment, if that is what you are suggesting. That feels like drudge-work with a side order of looking like you are grasping for cheap points.

Comment: @Spagirl "grasping for cheap points" that's why community wiki is recommended

Comment: @tchrist, it can indeed be reasonably argued that answering in comments, as you say, 'ruins the SE system', but it can **also** be reasonably argued that disabling comments ruins the SE system as well. It is debatable which of the two is more damaging.

Comment: Blocking comments for 7 days [on a question that is an hour old](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/592509/first-for-schools-exercise-cambridge-gives-the-wrong-answer) seems excessive to me. No, wait, it doesn't seem, it *is*.  We're also a community, and a community exists when there is communication. Expertise in anything cannot exist without dialogue, an exchange of ideas, which also includes answerers responding to OP's genuine doubts and queries.

Comment: My question should be so lucky to attract comments after 10 hours, let alone 7 days.

Comment: @Mari-LouA People were writing answers in comments, so that means the question gets locked. Your "dialogue" is not being blocked because this time I actually gave you a chat room. You are perfectly free to continue your chatting where it belongs.

Comment: It was one person, not people. And a chat room is provided for everyone who commented. You're spoiling me, be still my beating heart. Talking for myself: When I see a question with comments I sense a buzz, it looks "attive", I may be drawn to see what the fuss is and sometimes, not always, users' comments give visitors and the OP insights that are not proper answers but give a better understanding of the problem.

Comment: Ahh, just noticed that the question has been **unlocked**. Thank you, do you know that you're my favourite moderator in the entire universe. ;))

Comment: Creating a chat room creates an impression that the comments in question are private exchanges among a small number of people. This may be true in some cases, but often isn't: many comments, although nominally addressed to a particular person, are really meant for all future visitors to the page.

Comment: @jsw29 [Here's another epic fail](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/592573/why-do-they-use-competition-instead-of-competitor#comment1489048_592573). These happen constantly. Every. Single. Day. What do you honestly expect us to do when users cannot stop breaking SE? Delete the comment-answers? Lock the questions? Issue warnings and suspensions?  We need a solution to this, and since you don't like mine I call upon you to provide a solution that you approve of.

Comment: @tchrist Some questions are like playing pigeon toss (or whatever you call it). And in language, the closer you get to the wall, sometimes only a simple explanation is needed. Ergo, people answer in comments. Like the **venerable** Mr. Lawler. And things like: "How do you pronounce parenthesis?" A site on language language cannot expect the the precision of numbers. It just can't happen...

Comment: Since I'm venerable, I'll answer in a comment. Most questions here are simply the result of someone's confusion, which can be cleared up in a sentence or two. As I've pointed out before, the "SE system" gets "broken" here because it's a very  bad fit with the questions that arise about "english language and usage", the announced topic.. That can't be fixed by insisting on "our model here"; everybody has their own idea about what parts of the model are worth preserving, and which parts are just foolishness or bureaucracy. This can't be imposed from above; or rather, it can, but will it work?

Comment: @tchrist, the approach suggested by Mitch, above, seems reasonable to me.

Comment: You gave it to them straight @tchrist, and they can’t take it. They can’t be bothered to answer, and they break the system but it doesn’t matter because… Anyone else brought up children?

Comment: "What do you honestly expect us to do when users cannot stop breaking SE?" Fix SE so that it's not broken. That does not mean doubling down on rules; it means allowing information to flow. Like requiring questions from English learners to be distinguished from native speakers; or identifying languages spoken or countries and schools systems discussed. These would make comments unnecessary in many cases.

Comment: tchrist: I was planning to ask a meta question about this, but would you mind explaining the locking of [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/606505) post? I assume it was to pre-emptively prevent the '_me too, my mom used to say that_' comments, but I also feel that potential answerers could have used the opportunity to ask the OP for clarifications. (Sorry if this is the wrong place to ask this, but you said here that the reason is always given in the lock message, and I'm not seeing any explanation there. And I didn't want to make a massive deal of it.)

Comment: @Heartspring Because wicked people were answering in comments instead of answering in answers. I deleted those.